# SVG MAP extension

Tags: svg, qlikview

I am developing a dashboard with a map from australia using the SVG MAp extension for qlikview.

In qlikviewdesktop works correctly:

[image]

but when I load the report to the server and review it from the portal it doesnt show anything and actualy the property MAP is empty and the property SVG has a value:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: The simplest question first. Is the extention installed on the server or only on your local machine?

Comment: in both, server and desktop